# What is the purpose of configuration file?

Tags: opencv

I am trying to install opencv in my system by following [this](http://www.samontab.com/web/2012/06/installing-opencv-2-4-1-ubuntu-12-04-lts/) link. It says that after installing we need to do some configuration by opening

```
/etc/ld.so.conf.d/opencv.conf
```

and typing a particular address. And then in another one

```
/etc/bash.bashrc
```

we are writing

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH
```

It will be great if someone can explain how does it help the process.

Answer (score 1):

You're telling various parts of the system how to find the opencv support libraries.

### What the code does

The instructions that you cite say to add the following line to /etc/ld.so.conf.d/opencv.conf:

```
/usr/local/lib
```

Notice that `/usr/local` is in the bash config as well. When you build an application from source, the default install location is in the /usr/local subtree. The two configuration pieces you mention are there to make sure that the rest of the operating system knows to look in /usr/local/... in addition to the other usual places, for various libraries, etc. If you were to install into another location, say /usr or /opt, you'd want to change all those paths accordingly.

### Why bother?

[/etc/ld.so.conf](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/ldconfig.8.html) (and /etc/ld.so.conf.d) are there to tell [ld.so(8)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/ld.so.8.html) where to find shared libraries. Since opencv installs in /usr/local/..., we need to have ld.so look in /usr/local/lib to find the support libraries for the app. Similarly for pkgconfig, we need to be sure the pkg-config app can find its support files.

### Do you need to do this?

Now, you may not need to make the change suggested by the documentation. If you look at the other files in /etc/ld.so.conf.d, you may find that another file already includes /usr/local/lib:

```sh
grep /usr/local/lib /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*
```

On my system, this returns

```sh
/etc/ld.so.conf.d/libc.conf:/usr/local/lib
```

Because this is here, I wouldn't need a second entry, although it's safe to have it in twice. You may not need the PKG_CONFIG setup either, since the [pkg-config(1)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/pkg-config.1.html) man page states:

> On  most  systems, pkg-config looks in /usr/lib/pkgconfig, /usr/share/pkgconfig,           /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig and /usr/local/share/pkgconfig for these files.